# add react-native in existing node project

Tags: react-native

There is existing package.json with `npm start` pointing to `"babel-node server.js"`.

After doing react-native init in a separate folder, and then I am copying android , ios folders along with index.android.js and index.ios.js to existing node project. 
Then I also renamed new project root wherever they were being registered to new root such as in index.android.js ( `AppRegistry.registerComponent('newname', () => newname)`) and gradle builds

But it takes much longer time to start JS packager now in new project upon doing `react-native run-android` and is also giving concurrent.ExecutionException which it did not give with old root where `"react-native init"` was done.

Existing project also had relay and react which were upgraded to 0.14.8 for react and react-native itself is 0.22.2

What is recommended way to add react-native android to existing node project if not doing copy paste like above such that startup time still remains same [ emulator is of genymotion Nexus 5] ?

Comment: In which file/line does the ExecutionException is being thrown?

Comment: it is when running "react-native run-android"  - Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require (http://IP:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:6)

Comment: Line is - runJSBundle from CatalaystInstanceImpl.java : 171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you shouldn't be touching to the gradle/index.[android¦ios].js files when you change the root directory ; the paths are relatives meaning as long as you don't change your folder hierarchy it will keep working.

The best way to add react-native to an existing projet is to first add it via `npm` :
`npm install --save react react-native`

Then, copy your `android`, `ios` folders and your `js` files to the root of your project.
Copying/merging `.flowconfig` and `.gitignore` files is recommended (if you use git and/or flow).

You should be able then to start your project using react-native run-android.

I think your problem there is that you didn't install the npm packages in the new project (or maybe I am totally wrong)

Comment: thanks i will try this now , in case there is no initial android / ios folder, is there a way to do something similar to "react-native init" in this case  that will create index.android.js and android folder structures in existing project ?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but "react-native run-android" also probably creates folder structures in case it does not find them already ..

Comment: I find my build speed increases for JS packager once I rename my old .babelrc file -> do you have some good github link that I can follow along since the one I know from relay example for TodoMVC is dedicated native project, while I am looking for something where babel + react + webpack is already in use and native is brought in as well

Comment: I assumed you wanted to save your existing work in `android` and `iOS` folders ! I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what command is best if you simply want to init react-native in an existing project. Does `react-native init` wipe out the entire directory ? Eitherway, you can do `react-native android` and `react-native ios` after an npm installation to install android and ios folders.

Comment: react-native init does not allow with existing package.json file and exits there, i can try other one `react-native android`

Comment: I actually just did a `react-native init` on an existing package.json. Are you sure it doesn't work ? Everything seems fine here.

Comment: it had given me similar error - `Looks like React Native project already exists in the current
folder. Run this command from a different folder or remove node_modules/react-native`  . but I think that was due to package.json already having a mention to react-native as dependency.. You are correct about it

Comment: Yes, it means `react-native` is already listed as a dependency. Just run `npm remove --save react-native` if not done already